# UnicodeDecodeError with Django when I execute syncdb

Tags: python, mysql, django

I tried to set up Django with MySQL, but an UnicodeDecodeError occurs.
Would you please let me know how I can solve the problem? I searched about the Error, but I couldn't understand.

I found those codes and tried,

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return str(self.id) + ':' + self.name
```

and

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.name.encode('utf8')
```

But I couldn't solve the problem maybe because I don't know how to use def **unicode**() and those don't fit my columns.

Here are commands.

```
$ sw_vers
ProductName:    Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.11
BuildVersion:   15A284

$ python —version
Python 2.7.10

$ brew install mysql memcached

$ sudo pip install django mysql-python

$ python
    import django
    print django.get_version()
    1.8.5

$ cat /usr/local/etc/my.cnf
[mysql]
show-warnings
[mysqld]
character-set-server = utf8

$ mysql -u root -p
    GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO djuser@localhost IDENTIFIED BY ‘djpasswd’;
    SHOW GRANTS FOR djuser@localhost;
    CREATE DATABASE djdb CHARACTER SET utf8;
    FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
    USE djdb
    SHOW TABLES;
        Empty set (0.00 sec)
    EXIT;

$ python manage.py validate
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/validate.py:15: RemovedInDjango19Warning: "validate" has been deprecated in favor of "check".RemovedInDjango19Warning)

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).

$ python manage.py syncdb —database mydj
usage: manage.py syncdb [-h] [--version] [-v {0,1,2,3}] [--settings SETTINGS]
                        [--pythonpath PYTHONPATH] [--traceback] [--no-color]
                        [--noinput] [--no-initial-data] [--database DATABASE]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 351, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 343, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 385, in run_from_argv
    options = parser.parse_args(argv[2:])
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 64, in parse_args
    return super(CommandParser, self).parse_args(args, namespace)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/argparse.py", line 1704, in parse_args
    self.error(msg % ' '.join(argv))
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 68, in error
    super(CommandParser, self).error(message)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/argparse.py", line 2374, in error
    self.exit(2, _('%s: error: %s\n') % (self.prog, message))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 24: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Here are my setting files.

myproject/settings.py

```
# encoding=utf8

"""
Django settings for myproject project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 1.8.5.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/
"""

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'e76ziss5nexm#bzsaruxd2ikap$zy=aoemzy&1%czm+z&)ru$x'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'myproject.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'myproject.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    },
    'mydj' : {
        'ENGINE' : 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME' : 'djdb',  # DB名
        'USER' : 'djuser',
        'PASSWORD' : 'djpasswd',
        'HOST' : 'localhost',
        'PORT' : '3306',
        'OPTIONS' : {'read_default_file' : '', 'init_command' : 'SET storage_engine=INNODB', },
        'DEBUG' : True,
        'DEFAULT_CHARSET' : 'utf-8',
    },
}


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'jp-JP'

TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Tokyo'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

INSTALLED_APPS += (
    'myapp',  # アプリケーション
    'debug_toolbar',  # デバッグ
)


DEFAULT_CHARSET = 'utf-8'
FILE_CHARSET = 'utf-8'
```

myapp/models.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class myDB(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    body = models.TextField()
    c = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    u = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

I didn't have this kind of Error when I used centOS6, although those software's versions are different.
If you suggest me some pieces of solution or advice, it would be appreciated.
Thanks.

PS. I am new in this website, so I don't know how to ask properly here. I am sorry.

Comment: The problem doesn't seem to be related to the traceback; you just need two dashes before "database".

Comment: Hi, Daniel. Thank you for your reply. I am sorry I wrote wrongly. I execute with "--database mydj", but still have UnicodeDecodeError.

Comment: Thanks, I could solve this problem. I used the old version of Django in Linux and got used to, And what is worse is we only have 1.4-version-document in Japanese. So, I didn't know we are not supposed to use syncdb anymore.  I used migrate instead.