# I have auth_user table but createsuperuser notices OperationalError with Django1.8

Tags: python, mysql, django

I solved an Error on Django, but another error occured.
My settings are here -> 
[UnicodeDecodeError with Django when I execute syncdb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33099328/unicodedecodeerror-with-django-when-i-execute-syncdb)

```
$ python manage.py makemigrations myapp
$ python manage.py migrate --database=mydj
$ python manage.py createsuperuser --database=mydj
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 351, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 343, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 394, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/management/commands/createsuperuser.py", line 50, in execute
    return super(Command, self).execute(*args, **options)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 445, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/management/commands/createsuperuser.py", line 81, in handle
    default_username = get_default_username()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/management/__init__.py", line 177, in get_default_username
    auth_app.User._default_manager.get(username=default_username)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 127, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 328, in get
    num = len(clone)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 144, in __len__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 965, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 238, in iterator
    results = compiler.execute_sql()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 840, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 79, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 97, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 318, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: auth_user
```

However, when I check the table,

```
$ mysql -u root -p
[root@(none)]mysql> USE djdb
Reading table information for completion of table and column names
You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A

Database changed
[root@djdb]mysql> SHOW TABLES FROM djdb \G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
Tables_in_djdb: auth_group
*************************** 2. row ***************************
Tables_in_djdb: auth_group_permissions
*************************** 3. row ***************************
Tables_in_djdb: auth_permission
*************************** 4. row ***************************
Tables_in_djdb: auth_user
*************************** 5. row ***************************
Tables_in_djdb: auth_user_groups
*************************** 6. row ***************************
Tables_in_djdb: auth_user_user_permissions
*************************** 7. row ***************************
Tables_in_djdb: django_admin_log
*************************** 8. row ***************************
Tables_in_djdb: django_content_type
*************************** 9. row ***************************
Tables_in_djdb: django_migrations
*************************** 10. row ***************************
Tables_in_djdb: django_session
*************************** 11. row ***************************
Tables_in_djdb: myapp_mydb
11 rows in set (0.00 sec)

[root@djdb]mysql> DESC auth_user \G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
  Field: id
   Type: int(11)
   Null: NO
    Key: PRI
Default: NULL
  Extra: auto_increment
*************************** 2. row ***************************
  Field: password
   Type: varchar(128)
   Null: NO
    Key: 
Default: NULL
  Extra: 
*************************** 3. row ***************************
  Field: last_login
   Type: datetime(6)
   Null: YES
    Key: 
Default: NULL
  Extra: 
*************************** 4. row ***************************
  Field: is_superuser
   Type: tinyint(1)
   Null: NO
    Key: 
Default: NULL
  Extra: 
*************************** 5. row ***************************
  Field: username
   Type: varchar(30)
   Null: NO
    Key: UNI
Default: NULL
  Extra: 
*************************** 6. row ***************************
  Field: first_name
   Type: varchar(30)
   Null: NO
    Key: 
Default: NULL
  Extra: 
*************************** 7. row ***************************
  Field: last_name
   Type: varchar(30)
   Null: NO
    Key: 
Default: NULL
  Extra: 
*************************** 8. row ***************************
  Field: email
   Type: varchar(254)
   Null: NO
    Key: 
Default: NULL
  Extra: 
*************************** 9. row ***************************
  Field: is_staff
   Type: tinyint(1)
   Null: NO
    Key: 
Default: NULL
  Extra: 
*************************** 10. row ***************************
  Field: is_active
   Type: tinyint(1)
   Null: NO
    Key: 
Default: NULL
  Extra: 
*************************** 11. row ***************************
  Field: date_joined
   Type: datetime(6)
   Null: NO
    Key: 
Default: NULL
  Extra: 
11 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

I think I have auth_user table.
How can I solve the error?

Thanks.

Comment: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py Your settings are pointing to a sqlite database probably, instead of your mysql database.

Comment: Yes, the database is most likely not the same. Don't use the --database option if your settings are correctly set up

Comment: Thank you cdvv7788 and Alvaro. I changed my MySQL setting to 'default' in settings.py. And execute createsuperuser without --database. Then the problem was solved. Thanks.